# Calculus Problem Regarding Voltage, Differentials, and Linearizations

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential, linearization

I don't know how to begin solving this problem. If anyone could help me get the equations that I need and small hints, I would hugely appreciate it!

The voltage across a resistor is given by $V(t) = e^{-0.3t}\sin t$

a. What is the instantaneous rate of change of the voltage at $t=3$ and $t=7$.

b. What are the linear approximations (or linearizations) of $V(t)$ at $t=3$ and $t=7$? Sketch the voltage and linearizations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.  **Note:** You don't have to know anything about voltage (not even what it is) to do this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For part a, the "instantaneous rate of change of a function" at a given point is the derivative of the function at that point. So you need to take the derivative of the voltage and then plug in the given values of $t$. You will want to use the product rule.

b.) The linearization of a function $f$ at a given point $a$ is the function $g$ given by$$g(x) = f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)$$ So for instance, one linearization would be $$V'(3)(t-3) + f(3)$$

So you just need to plug in what you got for $V'(3)$ in part a.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! For part a I got .3996 and .117, are those answers on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.*

a. One interpretation of the derivative of a function at a point of its domain is as the rate of change of the function *at that point.* Can you now find the rate of change of $V$ with respect to $t$? In short, differentiate, then substitute the given values of $t$ to find the needed rates.

b. Since $dV=V'dt,$ then for small values of $\Delta t,$ we have that $dV\approx\Delta V,$ so that we have the approximation $$\Delta V=V'\Delta t,$$ or $$V-V_0=V'_0(t-t_0),$$ where $V_0,\,V'_0$ are the values of the voltage and its rate of change at the point $t_0.$ Can you now continue?

Finally, to sketch the voltage, note that it is a decaying sinusoid. Decaying because the exponential term decreases as $t$ increases, and $\sin$ is bounded. At the indicated points especially, the linear approximations will be the tangent lines to the curve.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I appreciate your time. For part a I got the answers .3996 and .117. There were no units other than voltage, so I just used v. For part B, I got the equations .3996x - 1.1772 and .117x -.804076 - I graphed them in Desmos but they didn't look like the graph you described?

Comment: @DakotaK The units would be Volts per second.

Comment: @DakotaK You're to graph those lines together with the voltage function. Those lines should be *tangential* to the decaying sinusoid that's the voltage curve at the specified points, as I explained in my last paragraph above.

Comment: Oh okay, yes that makes sense. I thought at first the the equations I got were what you meant, but I see what you mean now. That worked out. Thank you!